# how to deal with the need of multiple interfaces?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Hello I recently posted this question but very badly explained the problem, but i'll hopefully explain it better this time.

I have made this past project before with a Tab Bar, which one of the tabs lead to a `UITableViewController`, through `@interface` like so:

```
@interface NewsViewController : UITableViewController <MWFeedParserDelegate> {
```

Now I am doing a similar project where I am using a lot of the same code but it isn't using tabs, it uses `UIButtons` on a `UIViewController` to navigation around, and on one of my i want it to load the same `UITableView`, So i added the `tableView` to my project using IB, and now i have the problem as my original `@interface` for this particular header is a `UIViewController` like so:

```
@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController
```

So now i need my interface to load the `UIViewController`, and the `UITableViewController` under the same `@interface`, so then they both load and the same time, and that the `tableView` is then inside of the view.

Or is there something i should of probably changed in the .m file, which will tell it to load `tableView` as right now if i use:

```
@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController <MWFeedParserDelegate> {
```

I get errors saying i haven't declared `tableView`, and if i change it to `UITableViewController`, it obviously doesn't load the view.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to load the `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` at the same time?

Comment: I don't need to, but if i just load the UIViewControler, then it doesn't recognize tableView in my code even though UIKit is a framework in it, and is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just change the "original `@interface`" to be a subclass of `UITableViewController`, then connect the proper outlets in Interface Builder:

```
@interface NewsViewController : UITableViewController
```

If you load just the `NewsViewController` which is a subclass of `UIViewController`, it doesn't recognize `tableView` because it doesn't have a table view, it's not a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: If i did that how would i have it to also show the navigation bar i have to go back?

Comment: You would have the navigation bar if your `NewsViewController`'s parent is a navigation controller.

Comment: @alex, the navigation bar is solely handled by the navigationcontroller inside tableviewcontroller. so it should work.

-> navigatonController's pushViewController method is the way to go here.

Comment: Are you doing a navigation-based application?

Comment: no i'm not to put it simple i've got a view with  button, you push the button it loads a new view and then within that view i have a table views, and the reason it's a new view it's because it has a back button to go back to the first view

Comment: That's definitely a navigation-based application. If it is, then the navigation controller should be the root view controller set up in your application delegate and every view that you push would have the navigation bar with the back button.

Comment: okays, cheers man! i'll just work back start a fresh and sort it out, cheers once again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused between `UITableView` and `UITableViewController`. A `UITableViewController` is simply a subclass of `UIViewController` that manages a `UITableView` and adds some standard behaviour you might like for table views. It is all written in the [Apple UITableViewController Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).